# PHP SimpleXML incorrect format

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Servicos>
 <cServico>
  <Codigo>40010</Codigo>
 </cServico>
</Servicos>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Servicos>
 <cServico>
  <Codigo>40010</Codigo>
 </cServico>
 <cServico>
  <Codigo>40011</Codigo>
 </cServico>
</Servicos>
```

SimpleXMLElement works differently in the two XMLs below

```
 $object = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

In the first case it simply ignores the xml node "Servicos" bringing directly the "cServico" node already in the second xml as there is more than one "cServico" node it brings correctly, is there a way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to share the code you need fixing but, as general tip, you don't need to use the top level node when using SimpleXML:

```
$codes = array();
foreach ($xml->cServico as $item) {
    $codes[] = (string)$item->Codigo;
}
```

*([Online demo](https://3v4l.org/ff5X0))*